# Login screen upside down after upgrading to 17.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, login, 17.10

My login screen is upside down, and I don't know how to fix it.  My GNOME desktop was upside down as well.  I managed to correct that by running `xrandr --output eDP-1-1 --rotate normal` and that setting has managed to stick, but it has had no effect on the login screen.  How do I fix it?

For background info, this is on my MSI GS60 6QE laptop, with a GeForce GTX 970M GPU, using the latest nvidia drivers (384.90)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found the correct answer for this problem.  You need to add a xrandr command to the /etc/gdm3/Init/Default file.  In my case, I added `xrandr --output eDP-1-1 --rotate normal` just above the `exit 0` line at the bottom.  Of course that output parameter is specific to my hardware, but if anyone else is suffering from this, just run `xrandr --listmonitors` to isolate what the proper value for --output should be for you.

Comment: Nevermind, that solution didn't stick.  My login screen is back to being upside down, even with the xrandr command in the Default file.

Answer (score 0):

GNOME seems to treat the desktop as though it was running on a tablet.  I tried deactivating `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.orientation.active` (mentioned as a solution to the problem in an earlier Ubuntu version) on my laptop. It worked for a while but then stopped.

So I don't have a good solution, but you could try treating your machine as if it was a tablet and tilt it around a bit to see if you can get things back to the correct orientation.  It's not satisfactory, but it works for me.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but nothing worked.  I tried rotating my laptop around, the screen didn't budge.  I tried setting the orientation.active to false, nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, it was as easy as hitting this little button here:

New feature:

[image: new feature...]

Comment: Locking the orientation doesn't do much good if the login screen is upside down to begin with, with no means of rotating it to the correct position.

Comment: What worked for me was uninstalling iio-sensor-proxy (so `apt-get remove iio-sensor-proxy`). That disabled the rotation sensor whole. No idea on other fallout.